# How to replace multiple if statements i to more compact code/class in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm having a problem converting multiple if statements (like in the example below) into more compact code. I though about tables or multidimensional arrays, but maybe you guys know a better solution. I have about 30 if statements in my code and there is no clear pattern in them in order to easily convert that code to something faster and more compact.

How can I improve this?

```
if (D == 0.25)
{
    if (threadPerInch == 20)
    {
        le = 0.22;
    }
    else if (threadPerInch == 28)
    {
        le = 0.25;
    }
    else if (threadPerInch == 32)
    {
        le = 0.28;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use switch-case statement.

Comment: A Dictionary<int, decimal> where to store every value for le and threadPerInch

Comment: Switch to `Switch` Statement

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Steve mentioned Dictionary, which I think will compact the code even more. I can use it in a new class. I will try Switch as well.

Comment: @Thomas Please remember to upvote helpful answers and to [accept the one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) that solved your problem to mark your question as resolved.

Comment: @Thomas please avoid hard corded number like 32 instead of this you can try `int someValue = 32`

Comment: @poke I added some more details to my original post as I encountered some problem while applying the suggested solution to my problem. Should I do something else to refresh this question ?

Comment: @Thomas Please do not edit your question that significantly that late. That only invalidates the existing answers which is not fair for the effort the answerers took in helping you. You should undo your changes, upvote and accept answers here, and then create a new follow-up question for the new issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you only check for equality, you should use a dictionary that will essentially allow to do this lookup directly. For that, define ne mapping from `threadPerInch` to `le` as a dictionary somewhere, e.g. as a class member:

```
Dictionary<int, double> leForThreadPerInch = new Dictionary<int, double>() {
    [20] = 0.22,
    [28] = 0.25,
    [32] = 0.28
};
```

And then, you can just attempt to retrieve the value from it to get the `le` value:

```
if (D == 0.25)
{
    if (!leForThreadPerInch.TryGetValue(threadPerInch, out le))
    {
        // else case
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Switch` statement.

```
switch (threadPerInch)
{
    case 20:
        le = 0.22;
        break;
    case 28:
        le = 0.25;
        break;
    case 32:
        le = 0.28;
        break;
}
```

---

Or a `Dictionary`

```
Dictionary<int, decimal> threads = new Dictionary<int, decimal>()
{ 
    {20, 0.22m},
    {28, 0.25m},
    {32, 0.28m}
};

if (D == 0.25 && threads.ContainsKey(threadPerInch))
{
    le = threads[threadPerInch];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
    Dictionary<int, double> dict = new Dictionary<int, double>();
    dict.Add(20, 0.22);
    dict.Add(28, 0.25);
    dict.Add(32, 0.28);

    le = dict[threadPerInch];
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, a very basic element of any language is the [switch-case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) keyword. You could (not neccessary) store threadPerInch in another variable, then use switch like this:

```
ushort tpi = threadPerInch; //I suppose ushort, since its 20-32
switch(tpi)
{
    case 20: le = 0.22; break;
    case 28: le = 0.25; break;
    case 32: le = 0.28; break;
}
```

Make sure to always use `break;` after a statement. For additional control, use the `default:` keyword, which will get triggered if none of the cases are correct.

Comment: *“You should store threadPerInch in another variable”* – Why?

Comment: well, not __should__, but thats what I do and it makes it clearer in my opinion.

Comment: Why does introducing a new variable that has no clear name (`tpi`) make anything clearer? The variable already exists before and it has a very clear name, so you know exactly what you are switching on.

Comment: If you see it like this, I changed the text from `should` to `could (not neccessary)`.

Answer (score -2):

If these are are hard coded values in if else statement, as mentioned by you then you can use Tuple/Dictionary  to put the data and retrieve the value.

A small example of use of tuple is as below.

```
var population = new Tuple<string, int, int, int, int, int, int>(
                           "New York", 7891957, 7781984, 
                           7894862, 7071639, 7322564, 8008278);
// Display the first and last elements.
Console.WriteLine("Population of {0} in 2000: {1:N0}",
                  population.Item1, population.Item7);
// The example displays the following output:
//       Population of New York in 2000: 8,008,278
```

Thanks

Comment: Great suggestions from all of you - Thanks a lot. I will try all the options.